# Isolate x value within equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I isolate the `x` value here? (`x = ...`)

The equation:

```
20 = 18 + (47 * (x / 700) )
```

Any idea?

PS: I want to keep the initial values: 20, 18, 47, x and 700. Can I still isolate  by doing this?

Comment: Please include any attempts you have made. You are more likely to get helpful feedback about how to approach this type of problem than asking others to do it for you.

Comment: The hard part for me is the initial step which is escaping `(x / 700)`, sure I can show you `2 = (47 * (x / 700) )` if that's right? Apart from that I'm abit lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You begin with

$20 = 18 + (\color{red}{\text{stuff}})$

By subtracting $18$ from each side you get

$20-18 = (\color{red}{\text{stuff}})$

Now, on the left hand side, these are just regular numbers and you can perform the arithmetic to make it look simpler.  You get then

$2=(\color{red}{\text{stuff}})$

Now.  We can actually pay attention to what that stuff written in red actually is.  Just keep unpacking it one at a time.  Add, subtract, multiply, or divide or perform whatever other operation you need to do to "unwrap" or "untangle" the $x$ on the other side until all you are left with is $x$ on the one side and on the other is just a number after performing all the necessary arithmetic simplifications.

> Continuing, now we have $2 = 47\times (\color{blue}{\text{otherstuff}})$, so by dividing both sides by $47$...

Comment: Thanks but is it possible to keep the initial values: 20, 18, 47, x and 700 - and still isolate ?

Comment: Of course.  You just don't perform any of the arithmetic simplifications, so instead of $2$ you leave it as $(20-18)$.

Comment: Thanks I think I've got it: `(700(20-18)) / 47 = x`

Answer (score 1):

$20=18+(47(x/700))$

$20=18+(47/700)x$

$2=(47/700)x$

$1400=47x$

$1400/47=x$

Comment: Sorry I should have pointed out I want to keep the initial values: 20, 18, 47, x and 700. Can I still isolate `` by doing this?